# How to make URL rewrite rule in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a subdirectory query in my root domain, i.e., domain.com/query/.

Now I want to make a url rewrite rule by changing .htaccess file. Here is the file I made:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^query/(.*)$ query/index.php?action=$1 [NC]
```

But it is not working at all. I'm doing this on 1and1 performance hosting.

What could possibly be wrong? This is a big headache for me, and I have read some other posts on Stack Overflow. Thanks so much for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RewriteBase` and tweak your rule accordingly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /query/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```